# IE11 ignoring bottom 0;

Tags: css, internet-explorer

I have the following html elements:

```
<header id="w-header">
    <div> ... </div> 
    <img class="arrow-down" src="arrow.svg"> 
</header>
```

with this styling:

```
#w-header {
    height: 650px;
    background-position-y: -10px;
}

#w-header .container {
    padding-right: 20px;
    padding-left: 20px;
    bottom: 76px;
    position: absolute;
    width: 100%;
}

.arrow-down {
    position: absolute;
    bottom: 0;
    margin: 1px -2px -1px;
}
```

I can't understand why my '.arrow-down' element (which is a svg white shape) is not at the bottom 0 position.

Here is a screen shot:

[image]

It is working perfect in the rest of major browsers, even Microsoft Edge.

Thanks in advance

Comment: have you tried bottom: 0px ?

Comment: Yes @vals I tried it

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I finally get the solution. It seems that in internet explorer if you use a SVG image, you need to apply at least a "width".

Answer (score 0):

Try to use margin-bottom instead of bottom and position relative to outer container.

```
#w-header {
height: 650px;
background-position-y: -10px;
position:relative
}
#w-header .container {
padding-right: 20px;
padding-left: 20px;
margin-bottom: 76px;
position: absolute;
width: 100%;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

This is a guess, but perhaps it will work if you also define either `left: 0;` or `right: 0;` to the `.arrow-down` element.